# Node.js, JSON output

Tags: node.js, orientdb

I don't know how to put this but i have the below code to connect to orientdb then i'm running a query against a class, everything is working fine .

```
// app/index.js
//below the API to intiallize SERVER

var Oriento = require('orientjs');
var server = Oriento({
    host: 'xxxxxx',
    port: 2424,
    username: 'root',
    password: 'password'
});

// below is to initial database API 
var db = server.use({
    name: 'DBname',
    username: 'root',
    password: 'password'

});

console.log('I am using :', db.name);

db.open().then(function() {
    return db.query('SELECT FROM customers where @rid=12:1');
}).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    db.close().then(function() {
        console.log('closed');
    });
});
```

the result of the query is an output in JSON format 
My question is : I want each property returned from that query to be saved within a variable

Note: why i want this?  because i want to insert these variables into relational database....Am i following the right strategy ? if not please tell me what i can do

Thanks.

Comment: As you said  " i want each property returned from that query to be saved within a variable" . Which property you want to be stored in a variable?

Comment: lets say there is a property called first_name

Comment: It's totally depends on your requirement, You can create model (for relational db) and grab the result obtained from the query and assign that result to that model and store it in relational database.

Comment: "Am i following the right strategy ? " — No. Just use the property to construct your SQL query. Adding an intermediary variable is pointless.